# can't check if variable is undefined in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to solve compiler error " Object is possibly 'undefined' "

```
const destinationColumnIndex = (): number => {
  if (typeof result.destination === 'undefined') {
    return 0;
  }
  return boardData.findIndex(
    (column) => column.id === Number(result.destination.droppableId)
  );
};
```

but typescript compiler still tells me that "result.destination" may be undefined.

I have tried also:

```
  if (result.destination === undefined) {
    return 0;
  }
```

and:

```
  if (!result.destination) {
    return 0;
  }
```

and:

```
   if (!result || typeof result.destination === 'undefined') {
    return 0;
  }
```

and nothing works. Even thought it may be some bug so i restarted VS Code but there are still the same error.

EDIT - MORE CODE:

```
  const onDragEnd = async (result: DropResult) => {
if (!result.destination) {
  return;
}

const sourceColumnIndex = (): number =>
  boardData.findIndex(
    (column) => column.id === Number(result.source.droppableId)
  );

const destinationColumnIndex = (): number => {
  if (typeof result === 'undefined' || result.destination === undefined) {
    return 0;
  }
  return boardData.findIndex(
    (column) => column.id === Number(result.destination.droppableId)
  );
};
```

it's function inside of react component

Comment: does it say which object?

Comment: it underlines 'result.destiantion'

Comment: `if(result?.destination === 'undefined')`

Comment: it say "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'DraggableLocation | undefined' and 'string' have no overlap." When i do if(typeof result?.destination === 'undefined') same error as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do:

```
  if (result === undefined || result?.destination === undefined) {
    return 0;
  }
```

Checking `typeof` is not a good way to check for undefined.

or

```
  if (!result || result?.destination === undefined) {
    return 0;
  }
```

**UPDATE**

try this:

```
const onDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
  if (!result || !result.destination) {
    return;
  }

  const sourceColumnIndex = (): number =>
    boardData.findIndex(
      (column) => column.id === Number(result.source?.droppableId)
    );

  const destinationColumnIndex = (): number => {
    if (!result || !result.destination) {
      return 0;
    }
    return boardData.findIndex(
      (column) => column.id === Number(result.destination?.droppableId)
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: curious, why is using `typeof` not good for checking `undefined`?

Comment: unfortunately none of these work for me. There is still an error.

Comment: try changing the first to `result?.destination`. I edited in my answer

Comment: because checking for the value itself is basically the same thing but more straight forward.

Comment: where is the variable result declared? can you post the full thing?

Comment: @WilsonPena i edited question and added more code

Comment: It force me to refactor rest of this funcition code, but finally it works for the part i posted.